# Does the time machine backup include the backups of my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, time-machine, external-disk

I have taken a full backup of my iPhone on my MacBook (about 200GB), which has taken my MacBook storage to 90%! Then I have taken a backup of my MacBook using Time Machine on my external hard drive. My question: does the time machine backup in my external hard drive include the iPhone iOS backup?

I want to know because I want to delete the 200GB iOS backup from my MacBook. Both my iPhone and MacBook are running the latest OS.

Answer (score 2):

Time Machine makes a backup of everything in your computer, and since your iPhone backup is in your computer, it will back it up too.

To make sure, you can locate your iPhone backup in your Mac and then open your Time Machine drive and look for the same files in the corresponding location, and see if they have been copied.

According to https://support.apple.com/bg-bg/HT204215, your iPhone backups are located by default in `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`. Open that location in your Mac, have a look at how many files are there, how much space they take, etc. Then, once your Time Machine backup is done, open the backup drive, go to the current backup's folder, navigate to the same route (it should be `Users/(your username)/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`) and see if you have the same files. This way you'll be sure.

EDIT: be warned: if you delete the files in your Mac, the next time you use Time Machine it will delete them in the most recent version of your Time Machine backup too (though it will keep them in your previous version).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Time Machine backup does usually include the backup of the iOS device that you have stored on the MacBook itself.

You can choose to exclude directories from the Time Machine backup, so you can do that to avoid these backups to be backed up again.